# Persisting record in MySQL with Hibernate removes previous record

Tags: mysql, hibernate

My problem is when Hibernate persist record in the MySQL database, the previous record is removed and replaced by the new record.

Here is the

[Hibernate Mapping: Account.hbm.xml](http://pastebin.com/pd3n5zte)
and
[SQL Statement](http://pastebin.com/6cgiVXCm)

Which I used with Hibernate and with the MySQL database. I am not sure why records is being removed and replaced, is this a MySQL problem?

Comment: Is `username` an `Integer`? a `String`?

Comment: In my understanding, this is what a persistent record should do, I guess one of the concept of persistence is that you change your object and the changes gets reflected in database.

Comment: @Zohaib I am creating new Account object for each time createUser service is called.

Comment: ...like Account user = new Account(); for each service request called

Comment: @xybrek I could not open these links (its problem with my machine), If you have not posted code on any one of these links, can you please post it here.

Comment: Can you try these links: http://pastebin.com/pd3n5zte

Comment: @xybrek the only possible reason is that you're using the same `name` value for each created Account, as your only primary key is actually the name. Maybe you should use an new primary key `idUser` with `autoincrement` set on it... like this `\`idUser\` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment`... `PRIMARY KEY (idUser)`

Comment: I fixed the problem already. I change from "create" to "update" the value of <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely binding or setting the Entity ID.

This makes Hibernate think it's already saved, and thus update it -- overwriting your previous record.